# Can not connect my android project with parse-dashboard locally

Tags: android

Am trying to connect my android program to the parse server dashboard.
i have created the dashboard successful, i have tried searching everywhere,  but its like there telling me d same thing i have done,
here is my code
thank u..`

```
****StarterApplication.java****

    package com.parse.starter;

    import android.app.Application;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.parse.Parse;
    import com.parse.ParseACL;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;
    import com.parse.ParseUser;
    import com.parse.SaveCallback;


    public class StarterApplication extends Application {

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .applicationId("instagram99n990nm900b")  //application id
                .clientKey("instagjusohjwjikkjjoeoeh")  //master key
                .server("https://instagram914.herokuapp.com/parse/")  //serverURl
        .build()
        );

          ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
          gameScore.put("score", 1337);
          gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
          gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
          gameScore.saveInBackground();
          gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
              public void done(ParseException e) {
           if (e == null) {
                      Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
                  } else {
                      Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
                  }

              }
          });


          ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        // Optionally enable public read access.
        // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
      }
    }

    **MainActivity.java**

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
          return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any progress.?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Manifest File -

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in right steps but you have to set up read and write permission to Parse before write any Parse Logic. It Seems like below

1)   // Enable Local Datastore.

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
```

2)  // Add your initialization code here

```
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("instagram99n990nm900b")  //application id
            .clientKey("instagjusohjwjikkjjoeoeh")  // client key is optional.....                .server("https://instagram914.herokuapp.com/parse/")  //serverURl
            .build());
```

3) // set the read and write permission to Parse

```
 ParseACL p_ACL = new ParseACL();
 p_ACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);         
 p_ACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);

 ParseACL.setDefaultACL(p_ACL,true);
```

Now apply your Parse logic in MainActivity.java file